# Money-rails Gem currency symbol overlapping issue on some devices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bootstrap-5, money-rails

I'm using `money-rails` latest version. The `humanized_money_with_symbol` helper currency symbol overlaps with the value like shown in the image below:

[image]

Code -

`p = humanized_money_with_symbol product.price`

This works properly on the latest devices like MacBook, pixels, iPhones. The issue only occurs on some devices.

Gem details -

`ruby '3.0.0'`

`rails, '~> 6.1.4'`

`money-rails, '~> 1.15.0'`

`bootstrap 5` webpack version - `latest`

`fonts` - `Source Sans Pro, arial, sans-serif`

Attached video link below for more details -

[Money rails issue Video](https://vimeo.com/652790077)

Comment: It seems like a css issue to me, nothing to do with the gem.

Comment: This issue happens everywhere I use the `humanized_money_with_symbol` helper method. I don't have custom CSS for this helper.  

Actual code - `p = humanized_money_with_symbol product.price`

Comment: How does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: @spickermann `<p>₹480</p>`

Comment: It looks good when it renders and then suddenly overlaps. Refer to the attached video

Comment: We can't view the video without registering with Vimeo, but it's definitely a rendering (HTML/CSS) issue and not a Rails issue - Rails is returning the text correctly (I assume that's the currency symbol you want). I'd suggest you use the Inspector in your browser to take a look at the element and see why it's being moved around. Possibly a UTF font-rendering issue, too. If "The issue only occurs on some devices", the question is *which* devices. I suggest refocusing your question after a little more investigation.

Comment: @JohnP Thanks for the detailed answer. Yes, it was not a rails issue. The issue was due to fonts. My Font didn't support the generated currency symbol.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not a rails issue as suggested by others in the comment section. `Source sans pro font` didn't support my currency symbol.

Fix - Change the font family

`p.custom-font = humanized_money_with_symbol product.price`